# What costumes are these characters wearing?

Tags: girl-genius

The characters at the rather *eventful* party shown in a recent  [Girl Genius comic](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20170224) appear to be wearing some rather eclectic costumes, but on further inspection they seem dressed as characters from well-known franchises.

[image]

One woman appears to be wearing black-and-yellow Pikachu ears, and there’s a hulking individual whose red helmet with gold lightning bolts seems strongly reminiscent of the Flash.

Are any other popular works or franchises referenced by these characters’ costumes?

Comment: I am unsure about this panel, but [Sephiroth](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20161221#.WK_caWlMHqA) can be seen in another panel at the same party, so I think you are on to something about several of the costumes at the party resembling out-of-universe characters

Comment: Also, an [Aquaman](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20161216#.WK_dNWlMHqA) (or perhaps Poseidon)costume is seen in this panel

Comment: The [Blue Knight](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20161230#.WK_eoWlMHqB) from the video game *Castle Crashers* is visible in this panel.

Comment: The smiling guy towards the right with the visor and white turtleneck outfit is [Dr Radium](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/its-science-with-dr-radium/4050-46117/)

Comment: I think you should link to the particular strip http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20170224 to make it easier to find in the future.

Comment: Hmm, actually, do you want only the costumes shown in this strip, or also the costumes shown in previous strips in the same party?

Comment: @b_jonas - I did link to the strip.

Comment: @b_jonas - The more the better.

Comment: http://girlgenius.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Shoutouts_at_Grandmother%27s_Costume_Party

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(This answer is an empty template with the characters numbered.  Please edit answers into it.)

[image: panel 1 labelled]

[image: panel 3 and 4 labelled]

[image: panel 5 labelled]

- 1:
- 2:
- 3:
- 4:
- 5:
- 6:
- 7: Pikachu from Pokémon
- 8: <strike>The Flash from DC Comics</strike> [Lord Hater](http://wanderoveryonder.wikia.com/wiki/Lord_Hater)
- 9:
- 10:
- 11: Dr. Radium from *It's Science with Dr. Radium*
- 12:
- 13: [Bone](https://www.google.com/search?q=bone%20comic&client=safari&hl=en-us&prmd=isnv&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkhqXz3qvSAhWESyYKHa7eAucQ_AUIBygB&biw=320&bih=460#hl=en-us&tbm=isch&q=bone%20comic%20tophat&*&imgrc=oNTCWO0gunA03M:)
- 14: Not a reference out of universe: Probably one of the [Knights of the Hunt](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20170104), seen transforming [here](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20170116). Wasn't wearing a costume and no longer wearing armor.
- 15:
- 16:
- 17: Not a reference out of universe: Martellus wearing a lightning crown in reference to his ancestor who was known as the Storm King.
- 18:
- 19: Not a reference out of universe: The Master of Paris, looking as he always does.

Comment: I doubt main characters aren't wearing original stuff. So 15-19 is rather pointless.

Comment: I keep telling myself that #16 isn't really Granny from the old Tweety and Sylvester cartoons. For one thing, her hair doesn't seem to be up in a bun; instead it comes down around her shoulders. Also, Granny didn't wear that fancy necklace. But I decided to mention this impression anyway, in a comment.

Comment: 8 is almost certainly Lord Hater from Wander Over Yonder - http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/woy/images/3/3c/LordHater1.png

Comment: #6 is driving me nuts. I *know* this character. I can't think of a timeframe - 70s to 90s, possibly earlier. Something in my mind associates the word "playhouse" with it, but no luck with that.

Comment: Withywindle: My brain is convinced it's a Muppet, even though I can't find anything in the Muppet's wiki to confirm that.

Comment: @A.Giesbrecht I searched the muppets too! Same with Sesame Street. I definitely have seen this character - I'm convinced it was in the 80s which would have meant I saw it in Australia. I've spent a bunch of time searching, all for naught.

Comment: FYI for those unfamiliar with Girl Genius: 17's costume has been explained in-story as a reference to the character's famous ancestor. 19 isn't wearing a costume.

Comment: 19 is the Master of Paris, and is just dressed as himself. I don't think Agatha is in costume, just dressed pretty. #15 is Zola, dressed as an in-universe character called the Queen of the Dawn.

Comment: Ah, I accidentally submitted my edit before providing my full reasoning: changed the guess for 17 from Zeus to what @AGiesbrecht pointed out.